# JavaScript REST authentication

Tags: javascript, security, rest, authentication, client-side-validation

Are there any solutions to implement REST authentications for clients using only JavaScript?  JavaScript code is always readable by anyone. I read many posts about REST authentication here, but didn't find any answers.

Comment: The only solution I think is a (API)-Key or something. But how do I make sure that the Key only works for a specified domain? One line in the hosts file and I would bypass this check if it based on Javascript.

Comment: Do you mean creating an authentication mechanism wherein a user can enter their own credentials, and then a JS function on the page will authenticate using XHR, and not by having the page navigate to a different resource?

Comment: API-key solution for public facing APIs is useful because although you can change your hosts file and allow you to use someone elses API-key, the other 99% of users on the internet are not going to do that. So in order to make yours (or anyone else's) site usable, you'd just obtain an API-key via the provided channels. Since everyone will be legitimately using API-keys, if anyone starts to abuse their access, their key is revoked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax) which details how to do BASIC authentication in JavaScript with jQuery's AJAX methods.