# Use basic authentication with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

I am trying to create a basic authentication through the browser, but I can't really get there.

If this script won't be here the browser authentication will take over, but I want to tell the browser that the user is about to make the authentication.

The address should be something like:

```
http://username:password@server.in.local/
```

I have a form:

```
<form name="cookieform" id="login" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text"/>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text"/>
      <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" class="page"/>
</form>
```

And a script:

```
var username = $("input#username").val();
var password = $("input#password").val();

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}
$.ajax
  ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index1.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: '{"username": "' + username + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
    success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!');
    }
});
```

Comment: So you **don't** want the browser to handle the BASIC authentication? Why not just use form-based authentication?

Comment: @no.good.at.coding If you need to integrate with a third party API behind authentication (which is what I am trying to do - https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction#basic-authentication)

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback to add an HTTP header with the authentication information:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
```

Comment: i am using the example u gave but it doesn't work
`
    $.ajax ({
    url: "http://server.in.local/index.php",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader(“Authorization”, “Basic ” + encodeBase64 (“username:password”) );},
    succes: function(val) { 
  //alert(val); 
  alert("Thanks for your comment!"); 
  } 
});
`

Comment: `beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); };` works for me

Comment: Problem...If the credentials I pass fail, in Chrome the user is then presented with a dialog to enter username/pwd again.  How can I prevent this 2nd dialog from appearing if the credentials fail?

Comment: Won't this leave the username and password out in the open for anyone to see ? Even if its in base64 they can just decode it. Same with the answer below.

Comment: @calebB Basic authentication in general just leaves the username and password in the open for anyone to see.  This isn't just a problem with the method described here.  If basic authentication, or really *any* authentication is being used then SSL should also be employed.

Answer (score 390):

How things change in a year. In addition to the header attribute in place of `xhr.setRequestHeader`, current jQuery (1.7.2+) includes a username and password attribute with the `$.ajax` call.

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  username: username,
  password: password,
  data: '{ "comment" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});
```

EDIT from comments and other answers: To be clear - in order to preemptively send authentication without a `401 Unauthorized` response, instead of `setRequestHeader` (pre -1.7) use `'headers'`:

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  },
  data: '{ "comment" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `username` and not `user`?
Also it's not exactly the same: 
from the online docos and my experience it looks like it's not preemptive as some APIs require. In other words it sends the `Authorization` header only when a code 401 is returned.

Comment: @StefanoFratini - you are correct on both counts. Fixed the username field, and it's good to know about the preemptive auth vs responding only on challenge. Setting the header explicitly as in other answers will allow use of this 'passive' variant of basic auth.

Comment: for me the the above option didnt work, this worked like a charm.. thanks

Comment: See above comment, please correct this answer to indicate { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("user:pass") } as the correct header

Comment: I think the latest jQuery supports setRequestHeader instead of 'headers'

Comment: This is the answer for which I have been looking! The key bit in this answer for me is how the 'header' is used to preemptivly send authentication. My question here is answered by this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404452/phonegap-ios-ajax-request-never-completes

Comment: Adding authorization in the headers section did work for me. Thank you so much! I had to remove dataType = json to make work at my end.

Answer (score 65):

Use the [beforeSend callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to add a HTTP header with the authentication information like so:

```
var username = $("input#username").val();
var password = $("input#password").val();  

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}
$.ajax
  ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index1.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: '{}',
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
    },
    success: function (){
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 42):

Or, simply use the headers property introduced in 1.5:

```
headers: {"Authorization": "Basic xxxx"}
```

Reference: [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 35):

The examples above are a bit confusing, and this is probably the best way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  }
});
```

I took the above from a combination of Rico and Yossi's answer.

The [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa) function [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes a string.

Comment: This is a bad idea, because you will send the login information with *all* AJAX requests, regardless of URL. Also, the documentation for `$.ajaxSetup()` says "Set default values for future Ajax requests. **Its use is not recommended.**"

Answer (score 31):

As others have suggested, you can set the username and password directly in the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  username: username,
  password: password,
  // ... other parameters.
});
```

**OR** use the headers property if you would rather not store your credentials in plain text:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {"Authorization": "Basic xxxx"},
  // ... other parameters.
});
```

Whichever way you send it, the server has to be very polite. For Apache, your .htaccess file should look something like this:

```
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Whatever"
    Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers Authorization
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*?)$" origin_is=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

#### Explanation:

For some cross domain requests, the browser sends a preflight **OPTIONS** request that is missing your authentication headers. Wrap your authentication directives inside the **LimitExcept** tag to respond properly to the preflight.

Then send a few headers to tell the browser that it is allowed to authenticate, and the  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to grant permission for the cross-site request.

In some cases, **the * wildcard doesn't work** as a value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin: You need to return the exact domain of the callee. Use SetEnvIf to capture this value.

Comment: Thanks for the info that browsers send a CORS preflight request without auth headers! Details like this can cause hours of debugging!

Answer (score 23):

Use the [jQuery ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) function, that can set up default values for all ajax requests.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Basic XXXXX"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) does not work with basic authentication so the jQuery beforeSend callback won't work with JSONP/Script.

I managed to work around this limitation by adding the user and password to the request (e.g. user:pw@domain.tld). This works with pretty much any browser *except Internet Explorer* where authentication through URLs is not supported (the call will simply not be executed).

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489.

Comment: guess that security-wise it's a sane choice to not allow this

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 11):

There are 3 ways to achieve this as shown below

**Method 1:**

```
var uName="abc";
var passwrd="pqr";

$.ajax({
    type: '{GET/POST}',
    url: '{urlpath}',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(uName+":"+passwrd);
    },
    success : function(data) {
      //Success block  
    },
   error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
    //Error block 
  },
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
var uName="abc";
var passwrd="pqr";

$.ajax({
    type: '{GET/POST}',
    url: '{urlpath}',
     beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa(uName+":"+passwrd)); 
    },
    success : function(data) {
      //Success block 
   },
   error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
    //Error block 
  },
});
```

**Method 3:**

```
var uName="abc";
var passwrd="pqr";

$.ajax({
    type: '{GET/POST}',
    url: '{urlpath}',
    username:uName,
    password:passwrd, 
    success : function(data) {
    //Success block  
   },
    error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
    //Error block 
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi, i have tested all 3 methods. But it never produced the Authorization header. As dataType i need to use jsonp because doing crossdomain call. And calling application API which i have no chance to change. Directly from java http client it works. But i am not  able to handle it by jquery.

Answer (score 8):

According to SharkAlley answer it works with nginx too.

I was search for a solution to get data by jQuery from a server behind nginx and restricted by Base Auth. This works for me:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";

            # Not necessary
            #            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
            #            add_header Content-Length 0;
            #            add_header Content-Type text/plain;

            return 200;
        }

        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/.htpasswd;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8100;
    }
}
```

And the JavaScript code is:

```
var auth = btoa('username:password');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth
    },
    success : function(data) {
    },
});
```

Article that I find useful:

1. This topic's answers
2. http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html
3. http://blog.rogeriopvl.com/archives/nginx-and-the-http-options-method/